# Angular 9: Subscribe call causes page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make an app in Angular 9 that makes requests to the Google Books API.

However, the .subscribe call in `requestBookByISBN(isbn: string)` causes the page to refresh. I want to avoid this.

```
  private callAPI(isbn: string): Observable<GoogleBook[]> {

    return this.httpClient
        .get<{ results: GoogleBook[] }>
        (`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${isbn}&key=${ApiLookupService.API_KEY}`)
        .pipe(map(matches => matches.results || []));
  }

  public requestBookByIsbn(isbn: string): GoogleBook[] {
    const bookResults: Observable<GoogleBook[]> = this.callAPI(isbn);
    let books: GoogleBook[] = [];
    bookResults.subscribe(data => books = data);
    return books;
  }
```

EDIT: Here's a part of the component.ts file with the relevant parts of the code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BookServiceImpl} from '../../shared/Book/service/book.service.impl';
import {CopyServiceImpl} from '../../shared/Copy/service/copy.service.impl';
import {AuthorServiceImpl} from '../../shared/Author/service/author.service.impl';
import {FormControlSettings} from '../FormControlSettings/form.controls.settings';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {Author} from '../../shared/Author/model/Author';
import {first} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';
import {Book} from '../../shared/Book/model/Book';
import {Copy} from '../../shared/Copy/model/Copy';
import {SharedService} from '../../shared/services/shared.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {ApiLookupService} from '../../shared/services/api.lookup.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-addbook',
    templateUrl: './addbook.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./addbook.component.css']
})
export class AddbookComponent implements OnInit {
    // forms 
    public submitted = false;
    public loading = false;
    public error = '';
    public initAuthorsSubscription: Subscription;
    public authors: Author[] = [];
    public selectedAuthors: Author[]; // chosen in ng select

    constructor(private bookService: BookServiceImpl,
                private copyService: CopyServiceImpl,
                private authorService: AuthorServiceImpl,
                private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
                private toastr: ToastrService,
                public sharedService: SharedService,
                public apiLookupService: ApiLookupService) {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initAuthors();
        this.initBookForm();
        this.getInitAuthorsEvent();
    }

    public findAuthors(ids: number[]): Author[] {
        const authors = [];
        for (const id of ids) {
            this.authorService.findById(id).subscribe(value => authors.push(value));
        }
        console.log(authors);
        return authors;
    }

    public isbnLookUp() {
        console.log(this.apiLookupService.requestBookByIsbn(this.isbnControl.value));
    }

    public initBookForm(): void {
        // assinging form controls

        this.bookForm = new FormGroup({
        // more assigning going on here 
        });
    }

    public initAuthors() {
        this.authorService.findAll().subscribe(data => {
            this.authors = data.map((author) => {
                author.fullName = this.authorService.getFullName(author);
                return author;
            });
        });
    }

    public getInitAuthorsEvent(): any {
        this.initAuthorsSubscription = this.sharedService.initAuthors().subscribe(
            () => this.initAuthors());
    }

    public onSubmit() {
        // values are assigned here 

        this.bookService.add(book)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.toastr.success('Buch erfolgreich hinzugefügt!');
                    copy.reference = data;
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.amountControl.value; i++) {
                        this.copyService.add(copy).pipe(first()).subscribe();
                    }
                    /*this.sharedService.sendCloseModal();
                    this.sharedService.sendCloseModal();*/
                },
                error => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.toastr.warning(error);
                    this.error = error;
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Another guess is that there are conflicts with other subscribe calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the reason why it refreshes, but `bookResults.subscribe` is an asynchronous operation, so you essentially are returning an empty array and then at some unspecified point modify that to the full data.

You have two options to fix that particular issue: go in with RXjs or promises:

RXjs option:

```
  public requestBookByIsbn(isbn: string): GoogleBook[] {
    return this.callApi(isbn);
  }
```

And just let the component that calls `requestBookByIsbn` subscribe and set the data in the component at that point.

Promise option:

```
  public async requestBookByIsbn(isbn: string): GoogleBook[] {
    const bookResults: Promise<GoogleBook[]> = this.callAPI(isbn).toPromise();
    return await bookResult;
  }
```

I'm guessing that where the refresh is occuring is likely outside of the part you are showing us.

If you are redirecting to '/login' to check if the user is logged in, then in that redirect, you should add the current path as [history state](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state) or a query param, and then redirect to that path once the login finishes rather than redirect to '/'.

Comment: I tried putting `requestBookByIsbn` into ngOnInit() just to see what was causing it . For some reason it re-routes to /login even though I did not import router.

Comment: Do you have a route-guard to ensure you are logged in?

Comment: I use JWT and local storage to make sure Im logged in. I should have been clearer: It re routes me to /login which redirects me to /

Comment: It definitely sounds like your issue is with the router rather than the book results. Unless your `ApiLookupService.API_KEY` is causing the issue due to a getter and it having to check if you are logged in.

Comment: It does not look like the problem is with the router either, it works fine everywhere else - I guess it's a problem with the method callAPI instead.

Comment: Looks like I was right - the call gives back a 401 error because of the Authorization header in my http Client.

Comment: So, you either have a server-side redirect when you have an auth error, or you have an http interceptor that redirects on auth error?

Comment: I have an authorization header in all of my calls via httpClient. When trying to fetch data from the google books api I got a 401 error because of the authorization header. 401 errors redirect me to the login screen in a service of mine where I intercept errors.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61560189/angular-9-httpclient-ignore-header-on-one-call?noredirect=1#comment108895069_61560189